# is there a way to initialize an array of objects that is inside of the private section of another class using the constructor of that class?

Tags: c++

i have a class named "author" and another class named "book", i want to have an array of authors inside of the private of the class book, and i want to initialize it inside of the constructor.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class author
{
    string name;
    string email;
    public:
    author(string name,string email):name{name},email{email}{}
    ...
};
class book
{
    double price;
    string name;
    author writer[3];
    public:
    book(double price,string name,author writer[3]):price{price},name{name},writer[3]{writer[3]}{}
    ....
};
int main()
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

i get this error"no matching function for call 'author::author()'

Comment: slightly offtopic: does a book have 3 authors always? Wouldn't a `std::vector` be more appropriate, so that a book can have 1 up to n authors?

Comment: `writer[3]{writer[3]}` That is not how you initialise a member array with an array argument. And don't use a raw array. Use a vector as mentioned. Hard-coding max counts is bad.

Comment: What are those `...` meant to be? You should get a different error with the (incomplete) code you showed, about said invalid syntax. If you fixed your `book` constructor, it wouldn't be trying to default-construct `author writer` and show that error. So why does it seem to be? Post _all_ the code. Also, post the full error including _where_ it arises.

Comment: Please post the full code that could be helpful for as to debug the issue

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with constructors, but with the way you try to initialize C-style arrays. If you want to stick with C-style arrays, you need to explicitly copy all elements:

```
book(double price,string name,author writer[3])
    : price{price}
    , name{name}
    , writer{writer[0], writer[1], writer[2]}
{}
```

Note that this is not safe - compiler doesn't check size of array, so it would compile you you provided array of two elements, but you would have Undefined Behaviour. You also cannot use a loop unless `author` has a default constructor.

More reasonable way is to use `std::vector` - it lets you have any number of authors instead of fixed 3 for every book.

```
class book
{
    double price;
    string name;
    std::vector<author> writer;
    public:
    book(double price,string name,std::vector<author> writer)
        : price{price}
        , name{name}
        , writer{std::move(writer)}
    {}
    ....
};
```

Comment: You can also write a (templated) constructor that accepts a pair of iterators (begin and end).   That allows passing a list of authors from a simple array of `author`,  a `std::list<author>`, a `std::vector<author>`, or any other container - just pass their begin and end iterators.   Yet another option is to write a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list`.    Another is a parameter pack.      Some of those options (not all) can be used together.

Answer (score 0):

Raw arrays were not first class objects in C language, and they are not either in C++: you cannot assign to an array nor can you directly initialize it from another array. You can only assign to its individual elements, or initialize it from other elements.

If you really want to go that way, you will have to write:

```
book(double price,string name,author writer[3]):price{price},name{name},
    writer{writer[0], writer[1], writer[2]}{}
```

For that reason the standard C++ library provides `std::array` which is just a tiny wrapper around a raw array, but allows for direct initialization or assignment from another array. But as you were told in comments, what is the reason for a fixed size here when you could use a `std::vector`?